# How to add correlation ID to the java program?

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, log4j, correlation

I am new to the logging things. So, i want to learn anything about logging. Can someone tell me how to add correlation ID to java program. I am just learning about log4j and add it on my simple java program like logger.info("bla") and i want to add correlation ID, but still not pretty understand what is Correlation ID?, How to add correlation ID?, What does the function of using it?

I already tried to find some source and the code example but the explanation is not really helped me

I want to know the simple code example if u can give me.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Please read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help

Comment: You are using `Java built in Logger` or Apache `log4j` ?

Comment: @VishwaRatna apache log4j :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What is Correlation ID?

A [correlation ID](https://blog.rapid7.com/2016/12/23/the-value-of-correlation-ids/) normally is meant to group log messages of related requests to multiple applications/microservices, i.e. if service A calls service B within some user request you want to know which of the log messages from both services belong to the same request.

> How to add correlation ID?

You'd add it as a header to the http requests which is normally called X-Correlation-ID.
In most cases your point of entry would be some webserver like Apache Httpd or Nginx - so those would generate and populate the header.

You'd then put a filter/interceptor in front of your services to extract the correlation ID from that header and put it into Log4J's [Thread Context](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/thread-context.html). You'd also configure your log pattern to get the correlation ID from the Thread Context and display it in all log messages.